# how to prevent overlapping empty span tags?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I have a div container, with two main span tags. The first span tag is for the menu, in which I have page 1 span, page 2 span, and so on. Each page span has a display:block and a background image (which is it's sole purpose, no content preferred).

My issue is is that they overlap. I've made sure the main menu span is big enough.

Comment: spans don't get in spans, you should use divs as containers...

Comment: Show some code...

Comment: It's a good manner to provide html/css sample. You can always use http://jsfiddle.net for example.

Comment: what @darma said, especially since you're setting the spans to `display:block` anyway. `span` is an inline element, while `div` is a block-level element by nature.

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understood correctly, you have something like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <span id="menu">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <span>Item 3</span>
  </span>
  <span>
    Something else...
  </span>
</div>
```

The problem could be that you are trying to render a box (span with display:block) inside a span, which is natively inline. So, you might benefit from actually using boxes inside of boxes. I suggest something like this.

In your styles:

```
     ul#menu{
       display: block;
       padding: 0;
       list-style: none;
       overflow: hidden;
     }

     #menu li{
       float: left;
       padding-right: 20px;
     }
```

In your markup:

```
<div id="container">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <span>
    Something else...
  </span>
</div>
```

This way, you are keeping the semantics in your markup, stating that a menu is actually a list, but you are rendering something that looks like a horizontal navigation.

Inline elements inside boxes should always work properly, but the other way around you will find some funky effects in some browsers.

Comment: Pedantic corrections: the question said a `div` container, not a `span`. In your CSS, you should change `ul` to `#menu` and `li` to `#menu li`; also you have `pading: 0;`